# Windows 8.1 OMA MDM DM enrollment

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mdm, oma

I am trying to write MDM DM for windows 8.1. The docs, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36831 , say that the device should hit http://enterpriseenrollment.contoso.com/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc using GET and it expects a response like the following.

```
Response:
Request Full Url: http://EnterpriseEnrollment.contoso.com/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc
Content Type: text/html
Header Byte Count: 248
Body Byte Count: 0
Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
```

I have my windows 8.1 test machine running through a proxy that maps the url to my local webserver for testing. Once it is ready it will be deployed where this proxy is no longer needed. I have installed the proxy cert into the root trust storage in case that is an issue.

Issue: Device never sends POST to URL http://enterpriseenrollment.contoso.com/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc

I assume this is because my response is not correct maybe.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because the cert on the server was not externally verifiable. Once I changed to use the correct cert communication continued.

Comment: I have been doing the same. MDM DM for windows 8.1 but am not clear for windows enrollment flow and setup. can you please share your knowledge on the same. I have been going through MS MDM document. but enrolment steps are not clear. :)

Comment: any idea how the dm server url be sent to wip8.1 ? and which uri the device will poll to ?

Comment: no idea why it didnt email me these question sorry for delay been busy with new baby. Im back at this and still working on enrollment. I am working on getting the cert set up correct. How far have you guys made it?